# ordered fixed-length arrays in mongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm new to monogDB and trying to design the way I store my data so I can do the kinds of queries I want to. Say I have a document that looks like

```
{
    "foo":["foo1","foo2","foo3"],
    "bar":"baz"
}
```

Where the array "foo" is always of length 3, and the order of the items are meaningful. I would like to be able to make a query that searches for all documents where "foo2" == something. Essentially I want to treat "foo" like any old array and be able to index it in a search, so something like "foo"[1] == something.

Does monogDB support this? Would it be more correct to store my data like,

```
{
    "foo":{
        "foo1":"val1",
        "foo2":"val2",
        "foo3":"val3"
    },
    "bar":"baz"
}
```

instead? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *"foo2" == something*? or you mean `foo[2] == something`.

Comment: I was using a shorthand to mean that "foo2" is the second position in the array "foo", so "foo2" would be the same as foo[1].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schema you have asked about is fine.

**To insert at a specific index of array**:
Use the `$position` operator. Read [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/).

**To query at a specific index location**:
Use the syntax `key.index`. As in:

```
db.users.find({"foo.1":"foo2"})
```

Comment: That better @user3100115?

Comment: Thank you that answers my question.